How to pronounce the /i/ sound in hit/kid and still/live
I checked the /i/ sound in hit/kid and still/live on merriam-webster.com.
Although the /i/ sound should be the same everywhere, the one in hit/kid sounds closer to the /e/ as in bed. Is this correct? If so, are there any rules to pronounce the /i/ sound in different words?
BTW: I live in the US and am learning American English.
Thanks

I am British, and I pronounce them all exactly the same like in 'hit' here https://forvo.com/word/hit/

People in different regions may pronounce the vowels differently. I knew an American woman who, when she said 'curry', it sounded like 'kirry'.

Say them all the same and you can't go wrong. I am British, and I pronounce them all exactly the same like in 'hit' here https://forvo.com/word/hit/

One thing I've learned is that you should never trust a native speaker when they talk about vowels. We don't know what we're doing or why we pronounce some vowels one way and some another.

It varies by dialect.  In standard AmE there's quite a difference between /bed/ and /bid/ but in New Zealand when someone is sleepy they go to /bid/.   Hit, bid, live use the same vowel in my dialect, but the /i/ of "still" is much farther back in the throat.

For the record, if you use slashes for pronnunciation I think most people will assume you're notating IPA, in which the vowel in hit is /ɪ/ (near-close near-front unrounded) and the sound in bed is /ɛ/ open-mid front unrounded. /i/ is the 'long e' sound, as in free, and /e/ is the 'ay' sound in may. (Blame the aeiou 5-vowel system for taking all the normal letters, leaving common english vowels with weird ones)

Thanks for the comments. I just want to add a little background info: I live in the US and am learning American English

The/ɪ/ are the same in kid, still, live, and hit. But there is also live as in alive. Not the same. And this is the same in British English. Find it here: ship/sheep, a bin/bean etc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPhMK2beUwQ Others that contrast: hit/heat//kid/bid, live/give. Those are some basic minimal pairs. The John Trim book is for UK English but the sound from your question is the same. liv

I believe it might be a weak vowel thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger So e.g. if you stress still and live while hit and kid are more reduced, they'll have a slightly different vowel. This might be a better question for linguistics SE.

@Kaia Connected or fast speech can change almost everything. Nevertheless, the sound of /ɪ/ is the same in all of them/. For a learner, that's the main point here.

"...the one in hit/kid sounds closer to the /e/ as in bed..." I'm not sure we can have a solid answer unless you edit to explain more about this perception. Because right now my response is "Nuh uh!" (As I live in the southern US, I can also imagine some though not all of these getting the "two vowel" phenomenon that can be common esp in NC Piedmont, e.g. "still" being like "steal.") But for learners I would stick to "default" common pronunciations and let regional dialects be picked up gradually if at all.

@AndyBonner I was definitely thinking "regional variant" too: the first thing that came to mind reading OP's question was a New Zealand accent (like fəsh and chəps)! He's probably actually hearing a shwa sound in 'hit' and 'kid,' and not the 'dress' vowel. So, given that the examples are from the US, maybe this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English? Specifically the section titled "Backing or lowering of KIT." A quote: "The final change is the backing and lowering of /ɪ/, the "short i" vowel in KIT, toward the schwa /ə/."

@AndyBonner Thanks for your comments. Have you checked the online Merriam-Webster dictionary? Do you think the sound is the same from the dictionary? To my ears, the sound is little different in hit/kid and still/live.

Although the /i/ sound should be the same everywhere - really not true. There's considerable variation even with a single speaker, let alone all the speakers in a region. People simply do not pronounce exactly the same sound for every occurrence of a phoneme.

I believe you're hearing a difference in length. The /ɪ/ in hit and kid is especially short because it's followed by a stop consonant, and the one in still and live lasts a little longer. The quality is the same. The /ɛ/ in bed is short for the same reason, but has a different quality.
This difference is all but undetectable to native speakers. Just learn to recognize both versions as the same sound.

The question notes that you are learning American English.  Let's focus on that.  If anything differs from country to country, pronunciation is at the top of the list.
In America, there are multiple regional accents with the most common being "General American English", which is either identical to "Midwestern American English", or at least close to it.
In that dialect, the near-close near-front unrounded vowel /ɪ/ sound is the same in "kid", "still", "live", and "hit". It sounds the same.
However all bets are off, if you get into the Deep South, or a strong New Jersey accent, etc etc.
The IPA references from multiple dictionaries corroborate this answer, indicating the sound is /ɪ/.
